# Refreshing tab content in openstack django webapp

Tags: django, html, openstack, openstack-horizon, openstack-heat

I am facing a weird issue in Openstack webapp where i am trying to refresh the tabbed content, however i end up appending the refreshed tab content to the the HTML DOM.

The flow of the code is simple except that i donot understand how the HTML is being attached to DOM instead of the existing tab.

The code flow is:

foo.get --->TabView.get --> TabView.handle_tabbed_response.

I desire that the tab be updated and not the DOM,

What have i done:

```
Class foo((tabs.TabView):
    tab_group_class = (barTabs)
    template_name = 'project/xyz/index.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ######## Business Logic
        thelper = business_logic(request)
        thelper.add_data(request)
        return super(foo, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(foo, self).get_initial()
        return initial

class TabView(generic.TemplateView):
    """
    A generic class-based view for displaying a :class:`horizon.tabs.TabGroup`.

    This view handles selecting specific tabs and deals with AJAX requests
    gracefully.

    .. attribute:: tab_group_class

        The only required attribute for ``TabView``. It should be a class which
        inherits from :class:`horizon.tabs.TabGroup`.
    """
    tab_group_class = None
    _tab_group = None

    def __init__(self):
        if not self.tab_group_class:
            raise AttributeError("You must set the tab_group_class attribute "
                                 "on %s." % self.__class__.__name__)

    def get_tabs(self, request, **kwargs):
        """ Returns the initialized tab group for this view. """
        if self._tab_group is None:
            self._tab_group = self.tab_group_class(request, **kwargs)
        return self._tab_group

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """ Adds the ``tab_group`` variable to the context data. """
        context = super(TabView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            tab_group = self.get_tabs(self.request, **kwargs)
            context["tab_group"] = tab_group
            # Make sure our data is pre-loaded to capture errors.
            context["tab_group"].load_tab_data()
        except Exception:
            exceptions.handle(self.request)
        return context

    def handle_tabbed_response(self, tab_group, context):
        """
        Sends back an AJAX-appropriate response for the tab group if
        required, otherwise renders the response as normal.
        """
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            if tab_group.selected:
                return http.HttpResponse(tab_group.selected.render())
            else:
                return http.HttpResponse(tab_group.render())
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return self.handle_tabbed_response(context["tab_group"], context)

    def render_to_response(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(TabView, self).render_to_response(*args, **kwargs)
        # Because Django's TemplateView uses the TemplateResponse class
        # to provide deferred rendering (which is usually helpful), if
        # a tab group raises an Http302 redirect (from exceptions.handle for
        # example) the exception is actually raised *after* the final pass
        # of the exception-handling middleware.
        response.render()
        return response
```

Please help.